# JSP Sql Runstatement results within other queries

Tags: sql, jsp

I am running oracle sql query in my jsp page with rptstatement

```
<rpt:openStatement var="parentProjects">
select p.prj_project_id from kcrt_fg_pfm_project p, ... ..
</rpt:openStatement>

<rpt:runStatement stmtName="parentProjects" var="parentProResults" />
```

Now this query returns a list of ids. I want to use that list in other queries.

i can get the results of "parentProResults" by doing the loop and getting each item. But is there a way i can use the whole list as a part of the other query like

```
<rpt:openStatement var="parentProjects">
select p.prj_project_id from kcrt_fg_pfm_project p, ... ..
where p.prj_project_id in (<c:out value="${parentProResults}" />
</rpt:openStatement>
```

I have tried this but, its giving me blank. Is there a way to get the list as arrays? like parentProResults.list or something?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

RK

Answer (score -1):

y don't you put it in the same query?

```
<rpt:openStatement var="parentProjects">
select p.prj_project_id from kcrt_fg_pfm_project p, ... ..
where p.prj_project_id in (select p.prj_project_id from kcrt_fg_pfm_project p, ... ..)
</rpt:openStatement>
```